# Eclipse Android Exception : NullPointerException throws in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, gps

I created this application with the help of a tutorial to get the gps cordinates to my app. This is my problem I have used `SharedPreferences` to set the values when user enters. In this code i get the previous values (gps updates and maximum run time of the app) and compare them with some conditions and set new user inputs if valid. but here I get  NullPointerException in this code.

```
  import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.Preference;
    import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
    import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LocationGPSTrackerPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            Preference pref;
            Log.d("LocationGPSTrackerPrefs", " works ");
            pref = findPreference("pref_gps_updates"); // gps updated
            pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    int oldValue = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("pref_gps_updates", "0"));
                    if (newValue == null 
                            || newValue.toString().length() == 0 
                            || Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) < 30) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.pref_gps_updates_too_low), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    } else if (LocationGPSTrackerService.isRunning
                            && Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) != oldValue) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_prefs_restart), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            pref = findPreference("pref_max_run_time"); // change run time
            pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) { // hours
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    int prefGpsUpdates = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("pref_gps_updates", "0")); // seconds
                    int oldValue = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("pref_max_run_time", "0"));
                    if (newValue == null 
                            || newValue.toString().length() == 0 
                            || (Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) * 3600) < prefGpsUpdates) { 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.pref_max_run_time_too_low), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    } else if (LocationGPSTrackerService.isRunning
                            && Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) != oldValue) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_prefs_restart), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Logcat output**

```
    08-29 20:29:15.724: D/AndroidRuntime(2086): Shutting down VM
    08-29 20:29:15.724: W/dalvikvm(2086): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c29648)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmapv2/com.example.testmapv2.LocationGPSTrackerPrefs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.example.testmapv2.LocationGPSTrackerPrefs.onCreate(LocationGPSTrackerPrefs.java:22)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    08-29 20:29:15.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat so we know what and where the error is

Comment: sir i have postd it at the end of the code

Comment: Yes, I noticed after I commented. It is better to separate classes and logcat from each other when posting

Comment: What is at line 22? That's where your error is. It looks like `findPreference("pref_gps_updates");` is probably returning `null`.

Comment: sir the code is (pref = findPreference("pref_gps_updates"); // gps updated
  pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() { )  but i cant find where the problem occures. thank you

Comment: sir i know that findPreference is depricated but i dont know and workaroud here

Comment: [According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)) it isn't deprecated. Anyway, it looks like you don't have a pref with that key.

Comment: sir is that means the error does not occures because of  a error in this code?

Comment: You really don't need to call me sir but no the error is definitely in the code. You get NPE because `pref` is `null`. This means you have not set a `Preference` with the key `"pref_gps_updates"`

Comment: I think the exception happens in your LocationGPSTrackerService.class. have you prepare it properly before do the static call?

Comment: thank you for the help.  codeMagic i called you because you tried to teach me something. thats why :)  here is my code in LocationGPSTrackerService.class. http://pastie.org/9513239 any help is kindly appreciated thank you